# QueryString truncated in WebAPI RequestBody when request is manually composed?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I've confirmed I have the dropdown set to post and the URL is correct, because the string gets passed into my Web API project without error.  However it is cutting everything off of the string after the first parameter

Request Headers:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:52888
Content-Length: 35
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Body:

```
=name=TestName&date=10/15/2014
```

In the Web API project the only part that is passed is `name=Test Name`

I'm confident the query string is in the right format.  I'm wondering if anyone else can point me in the direction of what I might be missing.

*If I remove the = in front of the request body then nothing is received*

Comment: I've never known Fiddler itself to mess with a request. Do you have any extensions or rules enabled that might mess with the request? Also, how are you determining what is received by your API?

Comment: I'm running the API in debug mode which is how I know it's getting cut off.  I'm not aware of any extensions or rules that would be changing the behavior

Comment: OK, but what are you looking at in the debugger? If you're inspecting a model class, it could be that the request body is passed correctly but not parsed properly by WebAPI. If you haven't already, try taking a look at `base.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and see if that's different than what was sent.

Comment: My controller for the post is as follows: `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage AddCourse([FromBody] string courseRequest)
        {`

Comment: Yep, that's most likely the problem. Change it to `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]         public HttpResponseMessage AddCourse([FromBody] string name, [FromBody]string date)`.

Comment: I tried that and am recieveing the error `Can't bind multiple parameters `

Comment: Do you still have the leading `=` sign on your post body? Because that's also wrong and should be removed.

Comment: Ah, WebAPI only allows one parameter to be bound from the body. I hadn't run into that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signature like `AddCourse([FromBody] string courseRequest)` tells WebAPI to look for a POST parameter named `courseRequest`. But (when it is properly formatted) your request body doesn't have that parameter - instead it has `name` and `date`. When you misformat the request body by prepending an `=` character, it apparently causes the parser to decide that `name=test` is the value. But the second part of the query string is after an `&`, and is clearly a different parameter. It has nowhere to bind that parameter, so it just gets dropped.

There are at least two solutions here. One would be to pass the parameters on the query string instead of in the request body, and use a method signature like: `AddCourse(string name, string date)` (note removed of `[FromBody]`).

Another would be to create a model object that encapsulates the request, something like

```
public class AddCourseModel{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Date {get;set;}
}
```

and use that as the argument to your method: `AddCourse([FromBody] AddCourseModel model)`.

Comment: I went ahead and created the model, I like that better than creating a name value pair from the query string. Thanks so much for the help